# Image processing in iPhone - what is the best?

Tags: iphone, image-processing

I want to write an iPhone app - view image app.
And I have an example: [Example (newspaper reader)](http://www.sankei.co.jp/iphone/)

That example is a newspaper reader. But i like their image processing.
Their processing is:

1. Load low quality image (small resolution) first.
2. Continue load high quality image (high resolution) step by step. They divide image into 9 piece (A --> I). And then they load from A, B, C, ... to I. Done, we have a nice image.
       A B C
       D E F
       G H I

Here is the question :D:
- i want to know what is the technology they used in their application?
- What is the best method to processing image in objective - c (iphone :D)

Thanks verymuch for your help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: It's likely that they have already prepared those images on the server the way they need them. So they just need to load them one after the other. No image processing necessary.

Comment: thanks, hope that you right :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that wherever they have what you think is a custom UIImageView they actually have a UIWebView. The reason I say this is because when you load an image in a UIWebView it does this partial loading for you.

The way I would go about adding this is to have 2 images: a small load quality gif & a higher quality one you actually want to display.
Now wherever you would use a custom UIImageView instead place a UIWebView.

Load the webView with a little html string like this.

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img style=\"position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;\" src=\"%@\"/>   <img style=\"position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;\" src=\"%@\"/>", lowResURL, hiResURL];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

(Bring your own NSStrings called, lowResURL & hiResURL.)

Now it should load the first low resolution copy much quicker giving it a rough idea of what it'll look like while the other one loads on top of it showing the full image.

NOTE: This might not (and probably isn't) the way the app you pointed to does it but is the quickest/easiest way to achieve the effect you described.

Comment: thanks, but i think they are not use WebView cause they have download all of image while viewing (if they use webview, i think they do not need to download image =.=)